# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'util:properties'

Tags: spring, xsd

my spring config file goes like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
.
.
.
<util:properties id="mailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${mail.smtp.auth}</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.quitwait">${mail.smtp.quitwait}</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.debug">${mail.smtp.debug}</prop>
    </util:properties>
```

I am getting below error in config xml file

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

let me know what needs to be done

Comment: What version of spring are you using?
Does it match the version number in your xsi:schemaLocation?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the -3.0 in front of all of the .xsd. 
I've run into this stupid error, and removing the version has worked version number has worked for me.

I can't tell you why this works. If you look in the org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.jar (for example) and find the META-INF/spring.schemas you'll find all of these

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd
```

You will find the schema there so why the XML parser complains is a mystery to me.